# Creating interpolation maps in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, interpolation, heat-map

I'm trying to create an interpolation map visualizing the global distribution of genetic markers - basically replicating the attached map. Can it be done in QGIS 3.8 (Zanzibar)?

I installed QGIS 3 but don't see the `'Interpolation plugin'` as downloadable (experimental & deprecated plugins enabled). Is it unavailable or found elsewhere?

[image: example_map]

Comment: Have you seen this article [Cannot find TIN Interpolation plugin in QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277990/cannot-find-tin-interpolation-plugin-in-qgis-3-0) ?